# scala udf complains"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"in flink sql client

Tags: apache-flink

The whole scala project for UDF is here:

[Flink_SQL_Client_UDF/Scala_fixed/](https://github.com/appleyuchi/Flink_SQL_Client_UDF/tree/master/Scala_fixed)

My operation to register the udf is like this:

```
①mvn scala:compile package
②cp table_api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar $FLINK_HOME/lib
③add the following sentence into $FLINK_HOME/conf/flink-conf.yaml
flink.execution.jars: $FLINK_HOME/lib/table_api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
④create temporary function scalaupper as 'ScalaUpper';
⑤CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_uid  BIGINT,
    product_name String,
    price      DECIMAL(32, 2),
    order_time TIMESTAMP(3)
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'datagen'
);
⑥select scalaupper(product_name) from orders;
```

Then I got

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ScalaUpper

[image: error]

Need your help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@needhelp. Thanks for your detailed steps to reproduce the probelm. I think we can solve this problem by using -j command in the sql client[1] to add jar into the java class path. In my local environemnt, it works. But I don't find any information about the 'flink.execution.jars' in the document[2]. Therefore, I am not sure whether this option works for the sql client.

When registering the function into the table environment, the function catalog just does a simple validation and add the <identifier, path> into a map. It doesn't load the class into the runtime. Only when the job invokes the function, the function catalog load the class into the runtime.

[1]https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/table/sqlClient.html#configuration
[2]https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/deployment/config.html